# android: how do I fix onBackPress listener?

Tags: android, string, android-edittext

I have a UI with a bunch of EditText lines for the user to enter data, c/f/gListenerEditTexts.  When the user enters data on fListenerEditText line and presses the Back key, the DiscardFragment dialog correctly opens.  If the user clicks "Ok" button on the dialog, the dialog closes, the data is discarded and the user is returned to the previous Activity.  My problem is that the gListenerEditText line does not work as expected when the user presses the Back key.  In this case, the DiscardFragment dialog opens for 1 or 2 seconds and then automatically closes and the UI returns to the previous Activity.  This happens without the user clicking on the "Ok" button.  What am I missing here?

```
EditActivity.java

public class EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity 

private ListenerEditText cListenerEditText,fListenerEditText,GListenerEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.activity_edit);

    cListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(id.CEditText);        
    fListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(id.FEditText);
    gListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(id.GEditText);

... 
cListenerEditText.setKeyImeChangeListener(new ListenerEditText.KeyImeChange() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            int stringToDo = cListenerEditText.getText().toString().replace(" ","").length();
            int stringDueDate = fListenerEditText.getText().toString().replace(" ","").length();
            int stringDueTime = gListenerEditText.getText().toString().replace(" ","").length();
            // If the EditText input line has data ("stringToDo") and the user presses the Back button,
            // then launch the DialogFragment to see if they really want to delete the data and
            // go back to the previous activity.
            if (stringToDo > 0) {
                FragmentManager fm3 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                DiscardFragment editNameDialog3 = new DiscardFragment();
                editNameDialog3.show(fm3,"s_dialog");
            }
            // when a date is entered by the user, this test works as expected
            else if (stringToDo == 0 && stringDueDate > 0) {
                FragmentManager fm4 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                DiscardFragment editNameDialog4 = new DiscardFragment();
                editNameDialog4.show(fm4,"s_dialog");
            }
            // when a time is entered by the user, this test is not working as expected
            else if (stringToDo == 0 && stringDueTime > 0) {
                FragmentManager fm5 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                DiscardFragment editNameDialog5 = new DiscardFragment();
                editNameDialog5.show(fm5,"s_dialog");
            }                
            else if (stringToDo == 0){
                // close the softkeyboard
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(dListenerEditText.getWindowToken(),0);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });    


DiscardFragment.java

public class DiscardFragment extends DialogFragment{

    public DiscardSkycardFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.discardfrag_layout,container,false);
        getDialog().setTitle("Discard");


        // When the user clicks "Cancel" in the "Delete" dialog, return to the CardViewActivity.
        Button btnCancel = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(EditActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);                
            getDialog().cancel();
        }
        });

        // When the user clicks "OK" to delete for the "Delete" dialog.
        Button btnOK = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
        btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dismiss();
            // Next line returns to the previous activity (MainActivity) by closing
            // the current activity (CardViewActivity).
            getActivity().finish();
        }
        });

        // handles when the user presses the Back Button when the "Delete" dialog is open.
        getDialog().setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
                // This filters the event as the back button press
                if (event.getAction()!= KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    // Next line dismisses the dialogfragment
                    dismiss();
                // Next line returns to the previous activity (MainActivity) by closing the fragment and
                // the current activity (CardViewActivity).
                getActivity().finish();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
cListenerEditText.setKeyImeChangeListener(new ListenerEditText.KeyImeChange() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
          if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            int stringToDo = cListenerEditText.getText().toString().replace(" ","").length();
            int stringDueDate = fListenerEditText.getText().toString().replace(" ","").length();
            int stringDueTime = gListenerEditText.getText().toString().replace(" ","").length();
            // If the EditText input line has data ("stringToDo") and the user presses the Back button,
            // then launch the DialogFragment to see if they really want to delete the data and
            // go back to the previous activity.
            if (stringToDo > 0) {
                FragmentManager fm3 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                DiscardFragment editNameDialog3 = new DiscardFragment();
                editNameDialog3.show(fm3,"s_dialog");
            }
            // when a date is entered by the user, this test works as expected
            else if (stringToDo == 0 && stringDueDate > 0) {
                FragmentManager fm4 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                DiscardFragment editNameDialog4 = new DiscardFragment();
                editNameDialog4.show(fm4,"s_dialog");
            }
            // when a time is entered by the user, this test is not working as expected
            else if (stringToDo == 0 && stringDueTime > 0) {
                FragmentManager fm5 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                DiscardFragment editNameDialog5 = new DiscardFragment();
                editNameDialog5.show(fm5,"s_dialog");
            }                
            else if (stringToDo == 0){
                // close the softkeyboard
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(dListenerEditText.getWindowToken(),0);
            }
          }
          return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ok.  Did you add or change anything else other than the "if(keyCode == ..." line?

Comment: Ok I will try that.

Comment: if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)   or if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)

Comment: No luck.  The dialog does not open for the user.  The Activity just closes and returns the user to the previous Activity.

Comment: user presses the Back key has  two event. ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP.

Comment: maybe that is problem

Comment: Please explain, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: try this. if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)

Comment: Ok that worked to launch the dialog for the user.  But I still have the same problem in that the dialog immediately closes and the user is returned to the previous Activity.  Somehow it seems like there may be a conflict with some other code and the dialog event is immediately consumed.

Comment: What is strange is that the other EditText (the fListenerEditText and the stringDueDate test) works perfectly as expected with my original code and with your ACTION_UP code.